# jQuery: problem with dialog height under IE

Tags: jquery, dialog

i'm experiencing problems with the jQuery dialog under IE8:

i'm first initializing the dialog, then change its height through the options:

```
div.dialog("option",{"height":y});
```

under firefox, anything is nice, but under IE the box is missing some height (about 50px), so i'm getting ugly vertical scrollbars.
any ideas what could be wrong?

thx

Comment: try removing any other stylesheet not directly related to the jquery dialog and see if that symptom remains. If it does not, it means your content zone is receiving styling instructions from other parts of your css code.

Comment: Might this be related to IE's mis-implementation of its box model?  Or has that been "fixed" for IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to initialize the height as specified in the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is one of two ways:

without the curly braces:

```
div.dialog("option", "height", y);
```

or with the curly braces (and without the "option"):

```
div.dialog({height:y});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height and width of the field so that once the dialog has been shown it reset the style of that field.

```
show: {
    effect: 'puff',
    complete: function () {
        $('#modifySubmit').css({
            height: "30px",
            width: "90px"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a little different problem. When window size changed, I changed the size of the dialog. In ie6 it does not work correctly. Help here is the solution.

```
var heightOfHeaderDialog = 35;
div.height(y-heightOfHeaderDialog);
```